# Unhandled exception input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

I would like to add exception handling in my program to display in a message box to the user. "Incorrect format entered please enter a numeric value" for my product price value. Currently when i enter a wrong format such as a string value i get an error message stating Unhandled exception input string was not in  a correct format. Instead of this i want a message box to appear. can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks. Code below i have used in my program.

```
 if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        // update the employee record

                        ((Employee)o).ProductName = this.textProdName.Text;




                        ((Employee)o).ProductPrice = Convert.ToDouble(this.textProdPrice.Text); 



                        ((Employee)o).ProductId = this.textProdID.Text;
                        ((Employee)o).ProductQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(this.textProdQuantity.Text);


                        MessageBox.Show(((Employee)o).ProdName + " record has been updated with new                       details, except the ID.");
```

Comment: my eyes really hurt....!! format that code please..[C# Basics Tutorial , Exception Handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use TryParse instead of doing a blind Convert assuming that the value might work. Then you don't need to worry about an exception being thrown you can just display your alert if the operation returned false.

Here's an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
double number;
value = Double.MinValue.ToString();
if (Double.TryParse(value, out number))
   Console.WriteLine(number);
```

If the operation is successful `TryParse` returns true and the value of number will be updated with the double that was extracted.